# Ninja Forms 3.0.11: <noscript>

Tags: wordpress, forms, noscript, ninja-forms

I am getting this no script error, and am unsure as to why.

Javascript is allowed in my browser, and the adblock is disabled. I see Ninja Forms 3.0.11 has a JS directory with several files.

```
<noscript class="ninja-forms-noscript-message">
Notice: JavaScript is required for this content.</noscript>
```

Has anyone come across this upgrading? If so, could you please explain how you resolved this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same problem today so I decided to switch themes and see if that fixed it. And that did fix the problem. So I switched back and it was still broken. I inspected the page and noticed there was a JS error in the console and I resolved that JS error that had nothing to do with Ninja Forms and it made my form show up and work fine now. So it seems if there are any JS errors going on it will affect it.

Comment: I'm sorry it took so long to respond. I do think you're right about it being a JS issue. I tried using another plugin and it did not work either.

When I was under the JS section of the inspect element, it was complaining about the CSS. Can bad CSS code really throw that in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of the scripts from your header and footers are getting added to the page correctly. I experienced this issue with an add on for ninja forms and my call to get_footer wasn't being included on the page and created this issue.

Answer (score 0):

i got same error:
 **Notice: JavaScript is required for this content.**

i removed my cache plugin Autoptimize, SG optimizer, the plugin used to combine js/css files etc,

it will solve your problem :)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Мy decision: add code `<? php wp_footer (); ?>` in the template file footer.php